# how to optimize mongodb find() query for large collections

Tags: php, mongodb, find, mongoid

I am using find("report.num"); in php script 
it is taking too much time and some time it shows code 0 fatal error 
even exception handler is not working on it

Is there any way to optimize this as my collection is so large????

Comment: Please, provide full query. ````find("report.num");```` has no sense.

Comment: Also provide an explain, also state the number of docs, also show us an example of the doc.

Comment: You could index the fields you are selecting from the document. Also, please, provide the information that was mentioned in the above comments.

Comment: Make sure you have persistent connection with MongoDB.